# question related to split() from regex java

Tags: java, regex, split

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    String s1=s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]"," ").trim();
    String[] word=s1.split("\\s+");
    System.out.println(word.length);
    for(String item : word)
    {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

i/p:-any string without alpha-bates(e.g. @##%&*%^$!@#$% ^#@%^ %$#@$ )
o/p:-1

above is my code but when i run it, it gives me a white space if i input some string not having a-z or A-Z like ';3#$@%^32'it returns a white space and also if i call array.length it returns 1 as size 
can anyone plz help me with it.how can i get empty(without even a white space) array at the end ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: @Turo that is exactly what OP does.

Comment: `String.split()` always returns at least one element. If you want to have an empty array in some cases, you need to handle those cases yourself. Eg. `if(s1.isEmpty()) word = new String[0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey If you want to check if something like @$%512 not in the text you can use it.
and if it's not what you looking for try to say it in another way

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String s = scan.nextLine();
    String regex = "^[a-zA-Z]+$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    System.out.println(matcher.matches());

    scan.close();
```